# How to increase target api level successfully

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to increase the target api level of my app without affecting other libraries that the app depends on, such as firebase and alike. I tried changing it in project structure under app module but this did not work out. Nothing changed in gradle file 
My next option is to increase it by editing the gradle file itself and increasing to api level 28. I am however scared of the effects this may have on the other libraries.
Below is my build gradle file, please assist me.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chomba.haroldking.kuta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation ' com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do I need to make changes to the other libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upgrade your `targetSdkVersion` you should update it in `build.gradle` together with the `compileSdkVersion` (you will get an error if you don't update it as well).

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}
```

Once you update the `targetSdkVersion` and the `compileSdkVersion` you'll also need to update the support library versions to `28.0.0`, because the support library's major version needs to match the `targetSdkVersion`. For example:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // instead of 26.1.0
```

Version `28.0.0` is the [final version of the support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions). To keep using the support libraries after you upgrade to API 29 you should migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

When updating you should also check if there have been relevant [changes in Android 9](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0) that you need to consider.

In your case you cannot update the `targetSdkVersion` without also updating the dependencies.

Comment: Does this mean I will also have to update the firebase dependencies? Do you know where I can find out what dependencies library versions such as firebase, correspond to the target api 28?

Comment: I suggest you just try it. You can check the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions) where the differences between versions are lined out.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried changing it in project structure under app module but this did not work out. Nothing changed in gradle file My next option is to increase it by editing the gradle file itself and increasing to api level 28.

Changing it in project structure wouldn't do any magic for you, you still have to follow the same process as you would by changing the gradle file.

> I am however scared of the effects this may have on the other libraries

Keep the 3rd party libraries up to date as well, using newer versions of libraries in older sdks will most likely cause issues as newer Android SDKs have behavior changes.

Here are some personal tips for migrating without being overwhelmed by the things it might break:

**1.** **Increment your target api by 1 each time and then fully test it**
For example, upgrade to api 27 from 26, test it and then upgrade it to 28 and so on. The reason for this is to narrow down and account for behavior changes in each api since the previous target api. Not only will it be less overwhelming, it would be easier to find solutions for the problems that might occur afterwards. If you migrate to 29 from 26 directly, it would be very difficult to identify the issue.

**2.**  **Read Migration Guides for each Android SDK**
These pages were really helpful in identifying deprecated classes/features being used even by third party libraries:
[Android 8.0 Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration)
[Android 9.0 Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration)

**3.** **If there is a problem in third party library after upgrading, it is most likely in Github Issues page. If it isn't there, create a new issue (following the guidelines listed there)**. There is no better place to get library specific answers than the repository site where the developers themselves can give you good suggestions.

**4. Read the changelog starting from the previous version of libraries that have issues.**
Some libraries have outdated documentation and newer versions can cause issues. For example, when I was migrating Dagger, there were some classes that were deprecated on newer versions but weren't documented and I only found out after reading the changelog.